# KKT condition - minimization problem

Tags: nonlinear-optimization, karush-kuhn-tucker

> $y^2-8 \ln(x+4)\rightarrow$ min,
>
> such that $-x^2 -y^2+9 \geq 0, y \geq 0$

*I have to find all ***possible*** optimal points.
*
Lagragian function is:

> $L(x,y,γ_1,γ_2) = y^2 - 8\ln(x+4)+γ_1(x^2+y^2-9) + γ_2(-y)$

KKT conditions are the following:

***FEASIBILITY:***

> $-x^2-y^2+9\geq0$
>
> $y\geq0$

***STATIONARITY:***

> $8/(x+4) + 2x γ_1=0$
>
> $2y+2yγ_1-γ_2=0$

***NON NEGATIVE MULTIPLIERS:***

> $γ_1 \geq 0$
>
> $γ_2 \geq 0$

***COMPLEMENTARY:***

> $ γ_1(x^2+y^2-9)=0$
>
> $γ_2(-y) = 0$

So I have to consider 4 cases.

***CASE 1)***
Both constraints are active:

$$\left\{\begin{array}{l}
x^2+y^2-9=0\\
y=0
\end{array}\right.$$
There are two real solutions, but just one point respects n*on negative multipliers condition*:
$$\left\{\begin{array}{l}
x=-3\\
y=0
\end{array}\right.$$
**(-3,0)** is a possible optimal point.

I have some difficulties with the other cases.

***CASE 2)***
The first costraint is non-active, the second constraint is active:

> $y=0 , γ_1=0$

So with stationarity conditions I have :

> $1/(x+4)=0$

that is not possibile.

***CASE 3)***
First constraint active, second constrait non-active:
$$\left\{\begin{array}{l}
x^2+y^2-9=0\\
γ_2=0
\end{array}\right.$$

***CASE 4)***
Both constraint are non-active:
$$\left\{\begin{array}{l}
γ_1=0\\
γ_2=0
\end{array}\right.$$

I dont't understand how to use the KKT conditions to find possible(or not) optimal points in case 2, case 3 and case 4.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Case 1:** You need also to check whether $(-3,0)$ satisfies all other conditions: from stationarity $8-6\gamma_1=0$ $\Leftrightarrow$ $\gamma_1=\frac43\ge 0$ OK and $\gamma_2=0\ge 0$ OK.

**Case 2:** No solution. (It does not have to have a solution in all cases.)

**Case 3:** From stationarity $2y+2y\gamma_1=0$ $\Leftrightarrow$ $2y(1+\gamma_1)=0$ $\Rightarrow$ $y=0$ since $\gamma_1\ge 0$. It means that the second constraint is active which contradicts the assumption for Case 3. Thus no solution.

**Case 4:** Similar to Case 2, no solution.

Conclusion: the only point that satisfies the KKT conditions is $(-3,0)$.

P.S. The solution is not reasonable since the function $y^2-8\ln(x+4)$ is clearly smaller when the logarithm is larger, that is the correct solution would be $(3,0)$. The error is in your stationarity condition: the partial derivative wrt $x$ is **minus** $8/(x+4)$. So you actually minimized the function $y^2+8\ln(x+4)$.

Comment: Thank you. Excellent answer. You are right, I made a mistake with the partial derivative.
Just one last question about complementary conditions: let us assume to be in the case where a constraint, with a γa multiplier associated, is active; besides, using stationarity condition, γa is 0. Can I say there are not any solutions for this case?

Comment: @DistribuzioneGaussiana It may happen that for an active constraint the corresponding multiplier is zero, it does not contradict anything. If all other conditions are satisfied it gives a legitimate KKT point.